# Go Gin middleware events

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm trying to make middleware for the Gin server to handle events during a single request because I need things like IP address from context and to not pass the whole context I'd rather pass my listener which makes my method not dependent on `gin.Context`.

I set up a server

```
func main() {
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())
    api := router.Group("api", middleware())
    {
        api.GET("test/:id", endpoint)
    }
    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}
```

and made a middleware

```
func middleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        listener := make(chan int)
        c.Set("EventListener", listener)
        go func() {
            select {
            case <-listener:
                fmt.Println("event called")
            default:
                fmt.Println("default")
            }
        }()
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

then I got an endpoint where I get my listener and then pass it to any function I want to

```
func endpoint(c *gin.Context) {
    listener := c.MustGet("EventListener").(chan int)

    id := c.Param("id")
    idInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    doSomething(listener, int(idInt))
}
```

and `doSomething` function to show that no context is used later on

```
func doSomething(listener chan int, id int) {
    if id == 1 {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: cause event and exit")
        listener <- int(id)
        return
    }
    if id == 2 {
        fmt.Println("WARN: cause event but continue")
        listener <- int(id)
    }
    fmt.Println("OK: everything is fine")
}
```

And the way it works now is:

when you call `GET http://localhost:8080/api/test/1` it will trigger event and exit

when you call `GET http://localhost:8080/api/test/2` it will trigger event and keep working

when you call `GET http://localhost:8080/api/test/3` it will not trigger event because all is ok.

So everything is working but only for one event along request. You can not call another one, because `select` already passed so my question is how to fix it and allow to trigger event multiple times.

I know I can make it like

```
for {
    select {
    case <-listener:
        fmt.Println("event called")
    }
}
```

but what would be stop condition of this loop?

I know there is something like `c.Done()` which is `chan` but have no idea how to use it in my case because I can make it like

```
for {
    select {
    case <-listener:
        fmt.Println("event called")
    case <-c.Done():
        return
    }
}
```

but how to pass that `c.Done()`? This `goroutine` does not stop.

Comment: Pass `c` as an argument to the function literal, or just reference it in the function literal directly since the surrounding block of the function literal does contain `c`.

Comment: It's not a solution for it

Comment: Seems like that [method](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/0f951956d0b8b4b459a2f46bcd4e7118f0306210/context.go#L1042-L1047) is not doing what its documentation states it is doing.

Comment: Kinda weird, but hopefully there was `c.Request.Context().Done()`

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is also `c.Request.Context().Done()` which works now, stopping `goroutine` and allowing to handle multiple events

```
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-listener:
            fmt.Println("event called")
        case <-c.Request.Context().Done():
            return
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: I think we should use a clone of Gin context in goroutines, as suggested in https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#goroutines-inside-a-middleware